# Strategy for achieving Romeo, Alpha, Delta (Fly over 5KM)?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

What are some strategies for completing the Romeo, Alpha, Delta (Fly over 5KM) achievement in Jetpack Joyride?

Looking for specific gadget combinations, utilities used, jetpacks and/or attire equipped (if they make a difference), and general strategy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the gravity belt and the turbo booster.

With the gravity belt equipped its safest to fly about 3/4ths up the screen. The gravity belt helps with your reaction time: you'll be able to drop below high zappers pretty quickly. Then get back up to the 3/4ths level as soon as you are able. At that height you can jetpack above any mid-level zappers.

The turbo booster is useful because you're invulernable every time you hit a boost.
Alternately you could try using the de-zapinator, but I didn't find it too helpful since it is unreliable.

It really just comes down to having split-second reaction times.

Answer (score 4):

I use the Lucky Last, Freeze-o-matic, Final Blast and a Revive.  Definitely keep 3/4th of the way up and try to collect tokens.  I didn't use the final blast until I reached at least 4500.  After using the blast I use a revive.  The Lucky Last is so you have a better chance of getting a free revive or blast.  Freeze-o-matic is there to get you some extra distance when you die.

It took me a bit but it worked.

Answer (score 3):

The turbo boost is nice but unreliable, I recommend the Gravity Belt and the Air Barrys. Remember that frustrating moment where you couldn't possibly have risen high enough to dodge that Zapper? Air Barrys make your initial jump almost instant and give you very high mobility up and down. You can't always stay in the middle of the screen and I find the Air Barrys more consistently help compared to the Turbo Boost.

In addition, if you have the coins, a well timed Revive (heart) or bomb can be just what you need to get a few hundred more meters. Save them up (I always had a few because I was required to buy them for challenges) until you have a good opportunity.

Comment: Using Air Barrys and running along the floor is a good way to go. I like the instant response of Air Barrys compared to the slightly slower response of Gravity Belt. One problem I ran into with Air Barrys is that due to that instant response you must have a clear area overhead when you jump. For me I just seemed to have some obstacle in the way just often enough that it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Turbo Boost and Gravity belt worked for me. Staying 3/4ths up on the screen is the best spot as Wallace said. It is additionally helpful because the vehicle tokens generally spawn around there and any vehicle will give you an extra hit before death. The vehicles have a bonus of slowing you down, with the exception of the hog.

In addition to turbo boost/gravity belt, I also had the big blast and second chance utilities. If you get hit, use the big blast and then when that is coming to an end, use the second chance.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously collecting lots of tokens on your way helps but i found the best way was to buy a pack of super head starts and a quick revive. I used ezy-dodge missiles and freeze-o-matic to make for a safer run and an extended finish.
Try to stay in vehicles for as long as possible too!

Answer (score 0):

just like they said, 3/4 of the screen is crucial. Once I got to 4,498 (my current high-score) with Lucky-last and Gift-token. By the time you get to the 4,000's, it's practically luck, so with a bomb or a double-life, you should be able to top my high by two meters (

Answer (score 0):

Try equipping Free Ride and Turbo Boost. If you're good with the vehicles, you should get a good start. I did that once and got a score of 8,030m.

Answer (score 0):

Air Barry - To quickly get you up...
Gravity Belt - To quickly get you down...

Try and maintain Barry at 3/4th level.

Also focus only on collecting Tokens as they will provide Quick revives and Blasts!!
Do not focus on collecting coins, they will often land you into troubles!!

I read this article, used this combo and completed the achievement in the first time!!

Comment: What article are you referring to?

Answer (score -2):

It's hard, but not undoable. I've only managed 7849 metres, here's my strategy:

Try using the Green booster to fly further, and try not to get killed fast or in shore distance.

Answer (score -3):

I used air barrys and gravity belt, with the help of a head start, final blast and a few vehicles I honestly managed on my third time xxx